# Is it possible to define an autowired list of interfaces via annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to implement a dispatcher in spring boot, with this simple code:

```
public class MyDispatcher{

   @Autowired
   private List<MyListener> listeners;

   public void dispatch(){
      listeners.foreach(listener -> listener.dispatch());
   }
```

Would it be possible to add each listener I define in the above list? 
Each listener would do something like:

```
@Component
public class AListener implements MyListener{
     ....
```

Comment: Yep should work, have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define it with `varargs`. For example:

```
public interface A {}
@Component
public class B implements A{}
@Component
public class C implements A{}

public class D {
private final List<A> listeners;
@Autowired
public D(A ... listeners) {
 this.listeners = Arrays.asList(listeners);
}  
public void dispatch(){
  listeners.foreach(listener -> listener.dispatch());
}
}
```

Comment: you can also use `List<A>` (or any collection) as the c'tor param and then you won't need to convert it to list

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work.

[Here's a link - scroll to 5. Injecting Bean References](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injecting-collections)